# jquery show()/Hide() not firing after first click

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I can't figure out why this script will not fire after the first click event.  The show() function works perfectly, but the hide() will not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".event.hidden").click(function () {
      var div_id = this.id.replace(/But/, 'Div');
      $("#" + div_id).show('slow', 'linear'); 
      $(this).attr("src", "images/but_hide_event.png");
      $(this).removeClass('hidden').addClass('shown');  
    });
    $(".event.shown").click(function () {
      var div_id = this.id.replace(/But/, 'Div');
      $("#" + div_id).hide('slow'); 
      $(this).attr("src", "images/but_event_info.png");
      $(this).removeClass('shown').addClass('hidden');
    });
});
</script>
```

The page in question is at http://randykrohn.com/schedules.php?Param=all

Comment: You're selecting things inefficiently. You shouldn't be repeating the same code twice like that, just the parts that change. If you think about how to re-design it like that the answer should be obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method. On document ready you are binding to `.event.hidden` but it doesn't match any elements. Once you run the show function, you'd need to rerun that selector. More simply, you can use .live():

> Description: Attach a handler to the
>   event for all elements which match the
>   current selector, now and in the
>   future.

Change it to

```
$(".event.hidden").live('click', function () { ...
```

and if you want to then be able to use the show again, you'll want to do this one too...

```
$(".event.shown").live('click', function () { ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Worked like a charm.  Not sure I understand your Description about attaching a handler.

Comment: No problem. The Description was just copy/pasted from the jQuery API. You can click the .live() link above to read up on it. It's a really useful method.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're attaching behavior to the `click` event of elements with class `event` and `shown` when the DOM first becomes ready. That is, once, on page load. But it looks like there are no elements with `.event.shown` at that time, since you're only swapping in the `shown` class *after* that first `click` event on elements with `.event.hidden`.

You should reconsider your approach -- or if you can't, you'll need to use `.live()` or `.delegate()` to watch for changes and *dynamically* attach new behavior to these `click` events.